# Oracle Where Case faster than the average run time by runners in the '5 Km Run' at the RM carnival held on the 4th April 2018

Tags: sql, oracle

So currently my query looks like this and displays all the runners who ran in the '5 Km Run' at the RM carnival held on the 8th September.

```
select 
    concat(competitor.compfname,competitor.complname) as fullname ,
    entry.carndate,
    carnival.carnname,
    entry.eventno,
    event.eventypecode,
    eventtype.eventypedesc,
    round((entryfinishtime - entrystarttime) * 24 * 60, 2) as duration_mins

from competitor
    JOIN entry ON competitor.compno = entry.compno
    JOIN carnival ON entry.carndate = carnival.carndate
    JOIN event ON entry.eventno = event.eventno
    JOIN eventtype ON event.eventypecode = eventtype.eventypecode

where 
    event.eventypecode = '5K'
    AND entry.carndate = '08/SEP/2018'

Order by
    entry.carndate,
    fullname;
```

Which gives me a table of :

```
FULLNAME      CARNDATE  CARNNAME                        EVENTNO EVE EVENTYPEDESC DURATION_MINS
------------- --------- ------------------------------- ------- --- ------------ -------------
AnnamariaRose 08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     35.23
FanShu        08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     44.73
JaneRyan      08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     18.23
LingShu       08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     45.73
NanShu        08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     42.73
Sam Ryan      08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     26.23
SebastianCoe  08/SEP/18 RM Spring Series Caulfield 2018 6       5K  5 Km Run     30.23
```

How do i add to the where statement so that the table only shows all the runners who ran in the '5 Km Run' at the RM carnival held on the 8th September 2018 which were faster than the average run time by runners in the '5 Km Run' at the RM carnival held on the 4th April 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
with ce as (
      select concat(co.compfname, co.complname) as fullname ,
             en.carndate, c.carnname,
             en.eventno, e.eventypecode, et.eventypedesc,
             round((en.entryfinishtime - en.entrystarttime) * 24 * 60, 2) as duration_mins
      from competitor co join
           entry en 
           on co.compno = en.compno join
           carnival c
           on en.carndate = c.carndate join
           event e
           on en.eventno = e.eventno join
           eventtype et
           on e.eventypecode = et.eventypecode
      <your query here with no order by>
     )
select ce.*
from ce
where ce.eventypecode = '5K' and
      ce.carndate = '08/SEP/2018' and
      ce.duration_mins > (select avg(ce2.duration_mins)
                          from ce ce2
                          where ce.eventypecode = '5K' and
                                ce.carndate = '04/APR/2018'
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AVG` analytic function to derive the average time, then filter for time > average:

```
WITH cteData AS (select concat(competitor.compfname,competitor.complname) as fullname ,
                        entry.carndate,
                        carnival.carnname,
                        entry.eventno,
                        event.eventypecode,
                        eventtype.eventypedesc,
                        round((entryfinishtime - entrystarttime) * 24 * 60, 2) as duration_mins
                   from competitor
                   JOIN entry ON competitor.compno = entry.compno
                   JOIN carnival ON entry.carndate = carnival.carndate
                   JOIN event ON entry.eventno = event.eventno
                   JOIN eventtype ON event.eventypecode = eventtype.eventypecode
                 where event.eventypecode = '5K'
                   AND entry.carndate = '08/SEP/2018'),
  cteWithAvg AS (SELECT d.*,
                        AVG(DURATION_MINS) OVER (PARTITION BY CARNNAME, CARNDATE, EVENTNO) AS AVERAGE_DURATION_MINS
               FROM cteData d)
SELECT *
  FROM cteWithAvg
  WHERE DURATION_MINS > AVERAGE_DURATION_MINS
Order by carndate,
         fullname
```

I'm guessing about the fields used in the `PARTITION BY` clause - adjust as needed.